# I want to understand the working of this Java program in detail? Why are we doing it and how are we taking such values to solve this?

Tags: java, byte, shift, signed

```
class shift_right {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char hex[] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};
        byte b = (byte) 0xf1;

        System.out.println("b = 0x" + hex[(b >> 4) & 0x0f] + hex[b & 0x0f]);
    }
}
```

I cant understand what's going on here

```
System.out.println("b = 0x" + hex[(b >> 4) & 0x0f] + hex[b & 0x0f]);
```

And why are taking 0xf1 and 0x0f.

Comment: Are you aware of bit-wise operations? If no then that would be a great starting point.

Comment: I know bit-wise operations but still I can't get this, why do we need to AND the number after right shifting with 0x0f cause the result is same after doing this operation that is 00001111. Please help me understand this.

Answer (score 1):

Just like I said in my comment, it seems that you do not have a clear grasp of how the bit wise operations work and how they can be used. My suggestion would be to do some exercises on bitwise operation so you know how they can be used. Nevertheless, I will go over what this code is doing?

### What is this code doing?

This code is converting the byte stored in variable `b` into hexadecimal form. The hex array just allows us to convert decimal to hex form. This is more of an intermediate step.

### Binary to Decimal?

Lets say we have byte `1010 1010`. To convert this into hexadecimal we can refer to binary to hex table

[image: Binary to Hex]

We know that `1010 1010` is `A A` which can be written as `0xAA`.

### How this code works?

From the conversion above, we know that we can convert 4 bits into hex directly. And the code is doing the same thing. However, the issue we face is how exactly will we take a binary number and convert it to hex 4 bits at a time.

This is where bitwise operations into play. They allow us to slice, clear, set, toggle etc... bit with relative ease. Lets say we have a hex `1000 1010`

We want to convert

`1010` -> A

`1000` -> 8

Bit wise AND can allow us to clear bits at certain position. If you AND a bit with 1, it remains unchanged. However, if you AND it with 0. Those bit get cleared.

**Step 1: Convert `1010`**

```
1000 1010
0000 1111 (0x0F)
---------
0000 1010 <- the MSB 4 bits are now cleared. This will allow us to convert the 1010 to hex easily
```

`1010` is `10` in decimal and the tenth element in array is 'A'. So `hex[10]` gives A.

Step 2: Convert `1000`

If we just simply do a bit wise AND with `0xF0`. The value we get is `1000 0000` which is `-127`, not `8`. We somehow need to write it to `0000 1000` which is `8`. This is where the shift to right comes in handy.

```
1000 1010 >> 4
---------
1111 1000 <- result of shifting 4 times
```

Now, you are probably wondering what the hell just happened. Why isn't the result of shifting 4 times `0000 1000`?

When the bits are shifted to the right, the signed bits is extended and takes place of the bits that were shifted. This is called [Arithmetic Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) which happens on signed byte(s) as opposed of [Logical Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) which is for unsigned byte(s). Arithmetic Shift is very similar to Logical Shift if the number is positive if the leading bit is 0. So, now to clear all the bits that resulted in sign extension, we need to AND the number with 0x0F

```
1111 1000
0000 1111 (0x0F)
---------
0000 1000 This is 8 in decimal and hex[8] gives us '8'
```

So in the end we get `"0x" + "8" + "A"` which is `"0x8A"`